# How to align DIV right or left or center in CSS without absolute positioning?

Tags: css, css-position

I would like to position some DIV by it's distance from the right side of the container, or from the left side from the container, or centered; but everything without of excluding it from the flow, like `absolute` does.

Is it possible?

The only thing I can is centered. I can't believe this is not easily possible!

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#first {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    right: 10px;
}

#second {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
}

#third {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The sample is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/vm3Lg835/8/

If I make `absolute` position, another DIV starts to ignore absoluted one...

**UPDATE**

Visual explanation of what I want:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Incredible!

Isn't this task have simple solution? Without any cheating / hacking??

I just want to set distance from right side. Why can't I do this with ONE property???

Comment: You want to place the red div to the right and green one on the next line?

Comment: Since your question is not clear but I assume you wanted some behavior like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/getanwar/vm3Lg835/5/

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain more.

Comment: @ManojKumar approximately yes, but not next "line". Green DIV should start next to any space, occupied by red.

Comment: @Dims i have updated my answer. You may check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one do what you ask, keeping the flow and your original html structure.

I also added a "centered" div, which you commented might be needed.

(As per request, I added a second group of 3 div's in below sample using margins only, and here is also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxvoLr5u/2/)

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#outer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
#first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#second {
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
    text-align: left;
}
#third {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -50px;
}

/* sample 2 */

#outer2 div:before {
    content: attr(class);
}
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    
    <div id="first">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    
    <div id="second">
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div id="third">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
  
</div>

<br />
<hr />
As per request, these 3 divs use margin only<br />
<hr />

<div id="outer2">

  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to have 10 pixels space from right side?

Comment: How you made `second` being aligned LEFT? By `text-align`? Shouldn't this property affect what is INSIDE element?

Comment: And if it is affecting element itself, the why can't I make it align right with it then?

Comment: @Dims Second is `display: block` and doesn't get effected by the "outer"'s `text-align: right`

Comment: @Dims The "Seconds" `text-align: left` I added to make whats _inside it_ align left, and doesn't effect itself.

Comment: I understand your way as one should apply text align right and make some DIVs `inline-block` to obey this, and others will disobey by default. Ok. But why margins are working for centering horizontally while not working for aligning right? How to understand this?

Comment: @Dims You can use margin for all, check my update fiddle link

Answer (score 2):

I would probably wrap it in another relative div that has `text-align:right` and then give first `display:inline-block`:

https://jsfiddle.net/aqvug8uj/2/

Comment: What if I have multiple DIV, some of which I want to align left, some of them right, and others -- to center???

Comment: Unless they should be on the same row, simply wrap each div in it's own wrapper and let the wrappers' text-align control the alignment, e.g. text-align:center.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best solution https://jsfiddle.net/vm3Lg835/6/

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
    flex-direction: column;
}

#first {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    right:10px;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#second {
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Is using `webkit` properties conventional? Why do they even writing their own library still didn't do it straightforward???

Answer (score 0):

I found your question to be a bit confusing, to be honest. If I have understood you correctly, aligning stuff the way you describe it is simple, to the point of being trivial, with `float` and `clear`.

```
#outer {
    width=100%;
}

#first {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;

    float: right; 
    margin-right:10px;
}

#second {
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;

    clear: right;
}

#third {
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve? Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLgc0ak5/1/).

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**
Add `margin-left: 100px;` according to your need.
It should work for you.
Take a look

```css
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width=100%;
}

#first {
    margin-left:350px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    right:10px;
    float:left;
}

#second {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    
    <div id="first">&nbsp;</div>
    
    <div id="second">&nbsp;</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:
HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="first">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="second">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    position: absolute;
}

#first {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    float: left;
}

#second {
    background-color: green;
    width:100px;
    float: right;
}

.clearboth
{
    clear: both;
}
```